# Optimize SELECT query for working with large database

Tags: sql

This is a **part** of my database:

```
ID  EmployeeID    Status    EffectiveDate
 1  110545        Active    2011-08-01
 2  110700        Active    2012-01-05
 3  110060        Active    2012-01-05  
 4  110222        Active    2012-06-30
 5  110545        Resigned  2012-07-01
 6  110545        Active    2013-02-12
```

I want to generate records which select **Active** employees:

```
ID  EmployeeID    Status  EffectiveDate
 2  110700        Active  2012-01-05
 3  110060        Active  2012-01-05
 4  110222        Active  2012-06-30
```

So, I tried this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee AS E
WHERE E.Status='Active' AND 
      E.EffectiveDate between'2011-08-01' and '2012-07-02'AND  NOT 
      EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Employee AS E2 
             WHERE E2.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID AND E2.Status = 'Resigned'
                        AND E2.EffectiveDate between '2011-08-01' and '2012-07-02'
             );
```

It only works with small amount of data, but got timeout error with large database.

Can you help me optimize this?

Comment: I assume you mean it fails on large volume. The problem is if you don't use punctuation in your sentences, it makes it harder to understand and you can miss the opportunity of getting help. For example I've read you last sentence and it took me a while to understand because it reads "it's working for large Volume data". If you add punctuation, then it reads correctly.

Comment: Why don't you use join instead of inner query? try to limit your query return with top 1000 or shorter date time if the data size is huge, or if did not have index, add the index

Comment: You should tag your request with the DBMS you are using. Which is it? Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL? ...

Comment: If you have an employee with two `'Active'` rows and no `'Resigned'` row, would you want to show both rows or only one? If only one, which of the two?

Comment: I need only active Employees in between dates (EffectiveDate between'2011-08-01' and '2012-07-02') ,   but resulted  employees  not Resigned in given time

Comment: Yes, but with two active rows, do you want to show both or only one of them? 110545 has two active rows. If they had no resigned row, which row(s) would you show?

Comment: I need show  only one  and once see the record   initially 110545  is active after they Resigned again they active

Comment: Ah, so it's about the latest status in that time range. If 110545's second active row were not 2013-02-12, but 2012-07-02, then you would consider them active. Correct? What is your DBMS?

Comment: I am working on sql server and my sql

Comment: Both? You are working with two different DBMS? And you haven't answered my Question. Is it About an employees last record in the given time frame?

Comment: No i am not taken, last record

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. Is it SQL Server? Is it MySQL? Is it really both? Is it about the last record? And if not, the old question remains, which row to show in case there are multiple active ones. Well, I've posted an answer that should work with MySQL and applies last row per employee logic. Hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I read your request: You want to show active employees. For this to happen, you look at their latest entry, which is either 'Active' or 'Resigned'.

You want to restrict this to a certain time range. That probably means you want to find all employees that became active without becoming immediately inactive again within that time frame.

So, get the latest date per employee first, then stay with those rows in case they are active.

```
select *
from employee
where (employeeid, effectivedate) in
(
  select employeeid, max(effectivedate)
  from employee
  where effectivedate between date '2011-08-01' and date '2012-07-02'
  group by employeeid
)
and status = 'active'
order by employeeid;
```

The subquery tries to find a time range and then look at each employee to find their latest date within. I'd offer the DBMS this index:

```
create index idx on employee (effectivedate, employeeid);
```

The main query wants to find that row again by using employeeid and effectivedate and would then look up the status. The above index could be used again. We could even add the status in order to ease the lookup:

```
create index idx on employee (effectivedate, employeeid, status);
```

The DBMS may use this index or not. That's up to the DBMS to decide. I find it likely that it will, for it can be used for all steps in the execution of the query and even contains all columns the query works with, so the table itself wouldn't even have to be read.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to achieve the above result set using Case Statements.
Hope this helps.

```
CREATE TABLE employee_test
(rec NUMBER,
employee_id NUMBER,
status VARCHAR2(100),
effectivedate DATE);


INSERT INTO employee_test VALUES(1,110545,'Active',TO_DATE('01-08-2011','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO employee_test VALUES(2,110545,'Active',TO_DATE('05-01-2012','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO employee_test VALUES(3,110545,'Active',TO_DATE('05-01-2012','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO employee_test VALUES(4,110545,'Active',TO_DATE('30-06-2012','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO employee_test VALUES(5,110545,'Resigned',TO_DATE('01-07-2012','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO employee_test VALUES(6,110545,'Active',TO_DATE('12-02-2013','DD-MM-YYYY'));
COMMIT;


SELECT * FROM(
                        SELECT e.* ,
                        CASE WHEN (effectivedate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2011-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND  TO_DATE('2012-07-02','YYYY-MM-DD')  AND status='Active')
                        THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS FLAG
                         FROM Employee_Test e)
 WHERE Flag='Y'
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer with another interpretation of the request. Just in case :-)

The table shows statuses per employee. An employee can become active, then retired, then active again. But they can not become active and then active again, without becoming retired in between, of course.

We are looking at a time range and want to find all employees that became active but never retired within - no matter whether they became active again after retirement in that period.

This makes this easy. We are looking for employees, that have exactly one row in that time range and that row is active. One way to do this:

```
select employeeid, any_value(effectivedate), max(status)
from employee
where effectivedate between date '2011-08-01' and date '2012-07-02'
group by employeeid
having max(status) = 'Active'
order by employeeid;
```

As in my other answer, an appropriate index would be

```
create index idx on employee (effectivedate, employeeid, status);
```

as we want to look into the date range and look up the statuses per employee.